# Workspace area stretches into menu bar

Tags: unity, 14.04, workspaces, menu-bar

I am running 14.04 Unity, I may have accidentally knocked my keyboard the other day (triggered keyboard shortcut but I can't find anything like this?) and now my workspace is stretching into the Panel at the top of my session, cutting off my browser tabs when windows are maximised etc. I tried web searches and found plenty about missing menu bars, how to hide, etc., but nothing that covers my problem. 
As per screenshot below you can see current tab just starting on the right edge of the address bar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ine.png

Better Example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKBz1.png

---

Update - 5 Dec 14
I have just done a fresh install of 14.04.1 and it seems I still have this problem, does everyone else have the same issue?  Such a hassle not being able to see the top of the window when maximized.

Comment: OK so it seems I have found the problem, although no working solution yet.  It seems to be related to my conky setup, as if i kill conky it resolves the issue, now to rework my conky configuration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the problem seems to be conky having an 'own_window_type = panel' possibly combined with my other settings.  Settings changed to:

own_window_type conky
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

All fixed